# Setting up Wireless on a Brother HL-2270dw on High Sierra

Tags: wifi, printing, java

Any ideas on how to set up wireless printing on a HL-2270dw for someone running 10.13.x (High Sierra)?

Most of the Brother instructions require 10.11 or 10.12.  The SetupWizard Java App crashes on 10.13.

```
/Applications/Brother/Utilities/WirelessDeviceSetupWizard/HL-2270DW/Utilities/SetupWizard.app/Contents/MacOS/SetupWizard
```

Results in

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/apple/mrj/MRJQuitHandler
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:1007)
    at java.base/java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:174)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.defineClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:801)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.findClassOnClassPathOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:699)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClassOrNull(BuiltinClassLoader.java:622)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:580)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    at SetupWiz.<init>(SetupWiz.java:119)
    at SetupWizard.main(SetupWizard.java:108)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.apple.mrj.MRJQuitHandler
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:582)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:185)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:496)
    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Do you need to use the setup app? Can you instead set it up the normal way?

Comment: I'm flexible.  What's the normal way?

Comment: Go to System Preferences>Printers & Scanners>+>Select the Printers and click add